# I-V curve of Zinc oxide film deposited on glass

Tags: experimental-physics, electrical-resistance, material-science, semiconductor-physics

Good day! I'm looking for any suggestion about my research. So basically my research is about electrical properties of ZnO film deposited on glass via spray pyrolysis. I want to determine the resistance of ZnO film, So using I-V curve and getting the slope i will be able to extract the Resistance. However, The results of I-V curve is noisy. It means that i don't have a typical I-V curve for ZnO film. (The contact is Top-top contact. Silver metal is used to deposit a Schottky contact). So what did think you the reasons of the noise? thanks!

Comment: How thick is your film? Are you sure, you have a closed layer rather than individual islands?

Comment: What do you mean by 'noisy'? Are you near the limits of your equipment? Or are you seeing large deviations in ohmic behavior? Why do you think the behavior of ZnO should be linear anyway (given that it is used to make varistors)?